# Change upload folder for a CPT

Tags: plugins, javascript, jquery

I have a CPT called "Musterkuechen". Users have access to a custom dashboard that I created with ACF Frontend. They do not have access to the wordpress backend.

When I create a new post in the backend of wordpress, all media ends up in the folder "musterkuechen".

However, when a User create a new post using the custom dashboard, the media goes into the standard uploads folder.
My script works in the wordpress backend dashboard, but not in the custom dashboard that I've made for my users.

What did I miss to make it work in the custom user dashboard?

Here is the Code:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'rrwd_upload_dir');

$upload = wp_upload_dir();
// remove_filter('upload_dir', 'rrwd_upload_dir');

function rrwd_upload_dir( $upload ) {

$id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
  $parent = get_post( $id )->post_parent;

  // Check the post-type of the current post
  if( "musterkuechen" == get_post_type( $id ) || "musterkuechen" == get_post_type( $parent ) )
    $upload['subdir'] = '/musterkuechen' . $upload['subdir'];

  $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
  $upload['url']  = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];

  return $upload;
}
```

Comment: You should check if the `$_REQUEST['post_id']` is set, e.g. `if ( empty( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) { return $upload; }`.. So with your custom dashboard, that variable may not be set or ACF uses a different variable/way to pass the post ID. And if that's the case, then you should ask the ACF community (forums). Nonetheless, you could try dumping the `$_REQUEST` and see if the post ID exists. E.g. Add `error_log( print_r( $_REQUEST, true ) );` at the top in your function.

Comment: Saw once how developers change upload directory for ACF fields with `acf/upload_prefilter` filter. Doc: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-upload_prefilter/ Example: https://gist.github.com/BODA82/a4b810b9c0f17fe4c52f7c7e96ade119